# Show changed lines only

Tags: diff, command-line-interface

I have a text file and I need the difference of that text file and show the only two lines before and two lines after the changes are made. iS it possible If diff can't do it, what tool can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the options (e.g. `-u` for unified of `-c` for context), you can eliminate lines that do not differ with the option:

```
--suppress-common-lines
```

Also look at the `-C NUM --context[=NUM]` and `-U NUM --unified=[NUM]` options to control the number of context lines.

Comment: Thank you David C. Rankin but I can't understand what you mean maybe it's  my problem.                                                                                                                       I am using this code                                                                                    Step1-- docdiff /tmp/01.tex /tmp/02.tex>/tmp/03.html                                                Step2-- firefox /tmp/03.html

Comment: Whoaa.. `docdiff` is not `diff`. I think we are talking about the same command, but your comment ` Step1-- docdiff /tmp/01.tex ...` has me worried. `diff` does just that it shows differences, but generally includes 3 context lines to help its brother `patch` locate the text to inserted/deleted, etc.. `diff /tmp/01.tex /tmp/02.tex>/tmp/03.html` was not designed to create a working `/tmp/03.html`. I've looked at `docdiff` on sourceforge, but will have to read about the options to see if what you are attempting is possible. I'll report back.

Comment: @Shalus checking the [**readme.html**](https://github.com/hisashim/docdiff/blob/master/readme.html) file for docdiff 5.0 it supports dumping the differences in 2 html files without tags, but not the creation of a working 3rd file from the differences in two LaTex files. e.g. `docdiff --line --html file1 file2`. I don't have `docdiff` installed, but reading it looks like the best you can do is `docdiff --line /tmp/01.tex /tmp/022.tex > /tmp/03.html` which would give you the differences in **01.tex** and **02.tex** in **03.html** (without tags unless present in **01 & 02**.